# alternating negative and positive value of slope and y-intercept in gradient descent

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear, gradient-descent, hyperparameter

I'm working with the following code for gradient descent for simple linear regression:

```
import numpy as np

def gradient_descent(x,y):
    mCurr = 0
    bCurr = 0
    iterations = 1000
    n = len(x)
    learning_rate = 0.0005

    for i in range(iterations):
        y_predicted = mCurr * x + bCurr
        cost = (1/n) * sum([val**2 for val in (y-y_predicted)])
        md = -(2/n)*sum(x*(y-y_predicted))
        bd = -(2/n)*sum(y-y_predicted)
        mCurr = mCurr - learning_rate * md
        bCurr = bCurr - learning_rate * bd
        print ("m {}, b {}, cost {} iteration {}".format(mCurr,bCurr,cost, i))

x = np.array([20, 43, 63, 26, 53, 31, 58, 46, 58, 70, 46, 53, 60, 20, 63, 43, 26, 19, 31, 23])
y = np.array([120, 128, 141, 126, 134, 128, 136, 132, 140, 144, 128, 136, 146, 124, 143, 130, 124, 121, 126, 123])

gradient_descent(x,y)
```

I'm facing two kids of errors:
1) The value of slope (m) and y-intercept (b) keep on alternating between negative and positive values:

```
m -5.0820333396910965e+35, b -1.0389559623628228e+34, cost 4.57760985674227e+74 iteration 997
m 5.5128418892908475e+35, b 1.1270291963079477e+34, cost 5.386601277550346e+74 iteration 998
m -5.980170468178623e+35, b -1.2225684777262613e+34, cost 6.338564061017721e+74 iteration 999
```

2) when i try to get rid of this error by hyper parameter tuning (i.e. changing the learning rate or the number of iterations), after a certain number of iterations I get NaN values for m and b and infinity value for cost.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? I've already tried changing the learning rate and the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gradient descent often suffers from poor conditioning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367397/for-convex-problems-does-gradient-in-stochastic-gradient-descent-sgd-always-p). We can precondition the data by centering it at the mean and scaling it by the standard deviation. [This is why it's common to center and scale variables when using gradient-based optimization as in neural networks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421927/neural-networks-input-data-normalization-and-centering).

$$
\begin{align}
y &= mx + b \\
\frac{y - \mu_y}{\sigma_y} &= \tilde{m} \frac{x - \mu_x}{\sigma_x}+\tilde{b} \\
y  &= \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}\left( \tilde{m}x - \tilde{m}\mu_x \right)+\sigma_y\tilde{b} + \mu_y \\
y  &= \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} \tilde{m}x - \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} \tilde{m}\mu_x +\sigma_y\tilde{b} + \mu_y
\end{align}
$$

So by inspection, we know that $m = \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} \tilde{m}$ and $b = -
\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} \tilde{m}\mu_x +\sigma_y\tilde{b} + \mu_y$ which we obtain using the centered and scaled data.

Using this converges to a result which agrees with R's `lm` printout to more than four decimals.

```
def gradient_descent(x, y):
  m = 0.0
  b = 0.0
  iterations = 10000
  learning_rate = 1e-4

  x_mean = np.mean(x)
  x_std = np.std(x, ddof=1)

  y_mean = np.mean(y)
  y_std = np.std(y, ddof=1)

  x = (x - x_mean) / x_std
  y = (y - y_mean) / y_std

  for i in range(iterations):
    y_hat = m * x + b
    cost = np.mean(np.square(y - y_hat))
    md = -2.0 * np.mean(x * (y - y_hat))
    bd = -2.0 * np.mean(y - y_hat)
    m -= learning_rate * md
    b -= learning_rate * bd

  m_true = y_std / x_std * m
  b_true = -m_true * x_mean + y_std * b + y_mean
  print("m {}, b {}, cost {} iteration {}".format(m_true, b_true, cost, i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  x_ = np.array([20, 43, 63, 26, 53, 31, 58, 46, 58, 70, 46, 53, 60, 20, 63, 43, 26, 19, 31, 23], dtype=np.float64)
  y_ = np.array([120, 128, 141, 126, 134, 128, 136, 132, 140, 144, 128, 136, 146, 124, 143, 130, 124, 121, 126, 123],
                dtype=np.float64)

  gradient_descent(x_, y_)
```

You already imported `numpy` so I've leveraged `numpy` functions.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me get the right cost value after the last iteration.