# What is the difference between feature scaling and weight initialization scaling?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-scaling

I build an MLP to classify instances of the fashion MNIST dataset. You can run/modify the code in [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ALsmYMI3UvSZVvE0SsNt4BI1Dauogbnj) Google Colab Notebook.

When the features are downscaled by a factor of 255 (`feature_scale_factor=255.0`) and the weights of the first dense layer are initialized with via glorot initialization with default settings (`weight_scale_factor=1.0`) the network converges fast.

When the features are not downscaled (`feature_scale_factor=1.0`) and the initialized weights are downscaled by a factor of 255 (`weight_scale_factor=255.0`) the network does not converge (or rather converges extremly slow).

Stating Sycorax says Reinstate Monicas answer on [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420231/effect-of-rescaling-of-inputs-on-loss-for-a-simple-neural-network) question,

> If we apply scaling so that inputs are $X_{ij}\in [0,1]$, then
>   activations for the first layer during the first iteration are are
>   $$X\theta^{(1)} + \beta^{(1)}$$
>
> and at convergence are  $$X\theta^{(n)} + \beta^{(n)},$$ where the
>   weights are $\theta$, the bias is $\beta$.
>
> Network initialization draws values from some specific distribution,
>   [usually concentrated in a narrow interval around 0](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ALsmYMI3UvSZVvE0SsNt4BI1Dauogbnj). If you don't
>   apply scaling, then activations for the first layer during the first
>   iteration are are
>
> $$255\cdot X\theta^{(1)} + \beta^{(1)}$$
>
> So the effect of multiplying by the weights is obviously 255 times as
>   large.

should the convergence behaviour of the network not be the same in both scenarios?

---

Here is the code you'll find in the notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

# Get fmnist dataset
feature_scale_factor = 255.0 # Model converges with scale factor of 255.0
(X_opt, y_opt), (_, _) = fashion_mnist.load_data()  
X_train, X_val = X_opt[:55000] / feature_scale_factor, X_opt[55000:] / feature_scale_factor
y_train, y_val = y_opt[:55000], y_opt[55000:]

fmnist_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
fmnist_train = fmnist_train.shuffle(5000).batch(32, drop_remainder=True)
fmnist_val = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val))
fmnist_val = fmnist_val.shuffle(5000).batch(32, drop_remainder=True)
print('\nDataset batch structure:')
print(fmnist_train.element_spec[0]) 

def my_glorot_initializer(shape, dtype=tf.float32):
    weight_scale_factor = 1.0
    stddev = tf.sqrt(2. / (shape[0] + shape[1]))
    return tf.random.normal(shape, stddev=stddev, dtype=dtype)/weight_scale_factor

#Build Model
mlp = Sequential([
    Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28], name='Flatten'),
    Dense(300, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=my_glorot_initializer, name='Input_Layer'),
    Dense(100, activation='relu', name='H1'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='Output_Layer')
], name='MLP')
print()
mlp.summary()
mlp.save_weights('model.h5')

# Compile Model
mlp.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.1),
            metrics=['accuracy'])

mlp.load_weights('model.h5') # reset model to initialization state
history = mlp.fit(fmnist_train,
                  epochs=2,
                  validation_data=fmnist_val)
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference would be in the first step in weights when you calculate the back propagation. To calculate the gradient NN will make a step in weights $\Delta\theta$. Although the product $X\theta$ is the same when you start, the first step $X\Delta\theta$ will be very different because the scales of $X$ are different, by two orders of magnitude in fact. Whether it slows down or speeds up the convergence is probably a function of many factors, and it happens so that in your example it's slower to scale the weights.

Comment: Does this suggest that making similar scale adjustments to the learning rate would produce consistent results between the two models? Why or why not?

Comment: Learning rate regulates the step size, so I think you're right.